# Get Relative path of website using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

for my website I am importing style sheet using jquery. but for some pages it is not working.see my directory listing:

```
-website
--index.aspx
--js/script.js
--css/style-1.css
--css/style-2.css
--new/demo.aspx
```

I have written import css as follows

```
var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/" + theme + ".css'>");
            $("footer").append(cssLink);
```

but for the new/demo.aspx I am getting error 404, is there any way that I can link relative to the path ?

please help me

Comment: whether all the pages are in the same directory level...

Comment: @ArunPJohny well it is not !

Comment: then the way you are using relative path to include the css may not work... look at your browser's network panel, you might be able to see some 404 status

Comment: yes I can see that, I am seeking help because of that issue